# Automatic/Programmatically enable Apps Scripts Addon's on Google Docs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-docs-api

I'm searching for this like crazy and I just can't find a answer.

Imagine this. I have a "master" account. Using the Docs API I will grant access to users to some documents. But I need my addon enabled in every file. The users that will have access to the documents are not under my organization G Suite or anything. They are random gmail users.

Is there any way to do it? (besides of doing it manually) I couldn't find it in the documentation.

Comment: I don't think that you can automatically enable an Add-on for a user outside of the domain.

Comment: I cant find the link so ill post as a comment. There is Early Adapter Program where you can bundle an add-on with a template. If the user doesn't have it installed. It will prompt them when they try to use the document.

Comment: @SpencerEaston Can you provide a link or documentation to this Early Adopter Program (or API doc)? I have a similar need and Internet searches have proven fruitless thus far

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to disable an add-on, but an alternate solution is to create a service model inside your add-on. Maintain a DB of users that have installed your add-on, using this you can develop a logic which user is allowed to use an add-on.

This is by far the best solution I can think of.