# Enabling an addon in a Google Sheet programmatically?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Is there any way to enable an add-on programmatically on a Google Sheet, without any additional steps from the end-user? The "publisher/app" owning the addon is the same one that has oauth access to the sheet (if that makes things easier).

Comment: You may refer with this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370341/automatic-programmatically-enable-apps-scripts-addons-on-google-docs). It stated that there is Early Adapter Program where you can bundle an add-on with a template. If the user doesn't have it installed. It will prompt them when they try to use the document. You may also check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/GO_srChlPDQ;context-place=topicsearchin/docs/category$3Achrome%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false) for additional reference.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108449/google-app-script-google-sheets-addon-is-not-enabled-for-the-new-spreadsheet-by