# Google App Script: Google sheets addon is not enabled for the new spreadsheet by default

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, add-on

Based on [Installed and Enabled](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled) states of Editor add-on, I have written code for each states on Google Sheets add-on.

The code is working fine when I test it using the script editor with **INSTALLATION CONFIG** set to **Installed and Enabled**. But when I test the published addon after installing, the state always remains disabled for the document.

To enable the add-on, I have to manually go to Add-ons >> Manage add-ons >> Click on the three dots of my installed add-on >> Click on "Use in this document". Please find below screenshot:

[image]

Now I need to know whether programmatically it's possible to enable the add-on for the document or not. I tried but couldn't find a way to perform it programmatically.

Any help or suggestions would be helpful.

**Edit**

I have found that [Data connector for Salesforce](https://workspace.google.com/u/0/marketplace/app/data_connector_for_salesforce/857627895310) is already doing this. After clicking "Click to enable the add-on", "Use in this document" gets ticked. So there must be some way to programmatically enable the addon. I have scoured each Google App Script article but I haven't found any piece of code to achieve this.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: I agree with the provided answer.

Comment: @TheMaster, I have made some edits, can you please check?

Comment: Your addon can still add menus onOpen. Using the adfon(like clicking a menu provided) enables the addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to programmatically enable an add-on for a spreadsheet.

As you can see in the reference you shared, enabling an add-on for a document can be done the following ways:

> Getting an add-on from the store while using that document, or
> Using a previously installed add-on in that document

You have to take into account that an add-on can be enabled *for a document*, not *for a user* or *for a domain*, so having the add-on enabled for all documents by default kind of breaks the idea behind *enabling* and the related [Authorization modes](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes).

#### Enabling an add-on via onOpen:

If your add-on contains an [onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onopene) trigger that adds an add-on menu with an item with which you can call an add-on function, clicking this item will effectively enable the add-on for your document. See, for example, [The complete lifecycle](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#the_complete_lifecycle).

#### File a feature request:

In any case, you can try filing a feature request in this [Issue Tracker's component](https://issuetracker.google.com/components/642720/manage#basic) if you think this functionality could be useful.

#### Reference:

- [Installed versus enabled](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#installed_versus_enabled)

Comment: @lamblichus, I have made some edits, can you please check now?

Comment: @Jayakrishnan Basically what [TheMaster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65108449/google-app-script-google-sheets-addon-is-not-enabled-for-the-new-spreadsheet-by#comment116029265_65108449) said.

Comment: @lamblichus, Agree. Can you please edit your answer to include the workaround to enable add-on. I will make it as an answer.

Comment: @Jayakrishnan I added a small explanation of how to enable an add-on by using it via onOpen. Please take into account that this is `Using a previously installed add-on in that document`, one of the expected ways for enabling add-ons, and cannot be used to enable the add-on for all documents programmatically.