# Enable Add-ons in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created an Add-ons for Google sheet but I would like to check that the add-ons is enable in the document and add a button to enable it in the settings. I didn't find any documentation about that.

Comment: Have you published the add-on in the GCP console?

Comment: Yes the add ons works well but I always need to go to settings and check `use in this document` while I have seen some add ons that before letting the user use the add ons add a button to activate the add ons without having to go to manage add ons -> use in this document

Comment: It's a domain setting, you have to speak to your domain administrator to have this enabled via the admin console.

Comment: Sorry, I probably misspoke, the add-on is available, but if I don't click on manage add-ons -> use in this document, I can't call my functions. I would like to do like Salesforce add-on which in their menu detect that the add-on is not activated and propose to activate it directly in the menu

Comment: [I don't think you can.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65108449/11551468)